# jqplot - Stacked, Multiple Series

Tags: jquery, jqplot, bar-chart

I'm using jqplot and specifically the examples from http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php to see if it can be used to show some data I have.

The first example chart in the link above show 3 bars for the month of May, and the last one shows a stacked bar. I'm wanting to combine these two ideas so that, for example, in May each of the 3 bars would be stacked with different values.

Does that make sense and any ideas on how I could go about doing it?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: so what you're asking is 'How do I change the chart in the first example so that the bars are stacked?' Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Essentially yes! It would be easy if there was only one bar for May, but I can't seem to do it if there are 3 (as I obviously would have to pass x number of values for each bar).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code differences on the two examples, essentially what the second example does to stack the bars is include the option 'stackSeries: true'.

There are some other options setup there too (in the stacked bar example) to control the margin, but that isn't required.

The stacked bar requires two or more series of data to display stacks. If for one month you don't have a value for a certain series then you can set it to zero and it shouldn't show on the stacked bar.

So, in answer to your question (if I understand it correctly) use the code from the first example but add the configuration option 'stackSeries: true'

Comment: No, this doesn't work. By adding stackSeries: true all that happens is that it will stack all 3 values from May into 1 bar. I need for May to show 3 bars, all of which will have their own set of stacked values. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah yes, now that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if jqPlot has this functionality inherent. If you haven't gone too far down the jqPlot road though you might want to use flot. That is what I've been using lately and I find it simpler and more capable of meeting my needs.

Flot URL: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: I guess I could change the charting engine, it's probably not much that hard to change the format of the values if I need to. So how would you do it in flot?

Comment: I don't know exactly since I have never done this particular thing, but I think the example at http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html would lead you to the answer. The example shows multiple plot types overlaid on top of the same chart regions. You could put two chart types, one with bars stacked one without stacked bars, into a single month. Here is a stacked bar example too: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/03/jquery-flot-stacked-bar-chart-example/